# Проверка что созданный треугольник существует и не является дегенеративным

Tags: java, геометрия

Здраствуйте, код по проверки дегенеративности есть, но если может кто подсказать если верно сделан или если есть другие варианты, а то вроде код есть а проверку дегенеративность не проходит))).

```
public Triangle(Point a, Point b, Point c) {
        
            if ((length1<=length2 && length2<=length3)&&((length1+length2) == length3))/*(((length1+length2) < length3)||((length1+length3) < length2)||((length2+length3) <
                    length1))*/
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Triangle is degenerative");
```

тут какбы должен пройти проверку но ничего не случается.

```
double length1(Point a, Point b) {
        double xDistanceSquare = Math.pow(a.getX() - b.getX(), 2);
        double yDistanceSquare = Math.pow(a.getY() - b.getY(), 2);
        return Math.sqrt(xDistanceSquare + yDistanceSquare);
    }
    double length2(Point a, Point c) {
        double xDistanceSquare = Math.pow(a.getX() - c.getX(), 2);
        double yDistanceSquare = Math.pow(a.getY() - c.getY(), 2);
        return Math.sqrt(xDistanceSquare + yDistanceSquare);
    }
    double length3(Point c, Point b) {
        double xDistanceSquare = Math.pow(c.getX() - b.getX(), 2);
        double yDistanceSquare = Math.pow(c.getY() - b.getY(), 2);
        return Math.sqrt(xDistanceSquare + yDistanceSquare);
    }
```

Comment: Напишите лучше расчёт площади (оно и само по себе пригодится), и по результату смотрите, дегенерат попался или нет. Раз даны три длины - то по Герону.

Comment: По-русски такие треугольники называются «вырожденными»

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз вам даны точки, то треугольник, конечно, существует, а вырожденность можно проверить, узнав, лежат ли точки на одной прямой
(собственно, через векторное произведение считается удвоенная площадь, как Akina уже отметил, только с координатами Герон не нужен)

```
public Triangle(Point a, Point b, Point c) {
   if ((a.getX()-b.getX())*(c.getY()-b.getY())-(a.getY()-b.getY())*(c.getX()-b.getX())==0)   
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Triangle is degenerative");
```

Если координаты внутри Point у вас не целые, то сравнивайте абсолютное значение указанного выражения с малой величиной (скажем, 1.0e-10 )

Comment: Если координаты в плавающих числах, то наверное не 1.0e-10 (относительная точность входных данных), а грубо говоря, 1.0e-10 умноженное на сумму абсолютных модулей всех 6 координат.

Comment: @Serge3leo Да, так более универсально, хотя 1.0e-10 всё равно взято от фонаря.

Comment: Это ж да, векторное произведение, оно же вычисление определителя матрицы, штука численно не устойчивая. 

По-хорошему, нужен иной, численно устойчивый алгоритм, скажем, хотя бы, сначала повернуть для обнуления углового элемента (вращение Гивенса). А для этого, наверное, оценка должна быть что-то в духе `7*pow(<точность входных данных>, 1/4)*sum(<абсолютных величин всех 6 координат>)`

Comment: Спасибо за советы

Comment: @user13921628 Хм. Оказывается, я ответил на 5 ваших вопросов, в т.ч. на EngSO, но ни одного ответа не принято.

Comment: Незнал что надо),сечас исправим

Comment: я смотрю вы спец по математике